# How to to get Parent's DataContext inside TextBox.Template?

Tags: c#, wpf

The `Label.Binding` outside `TextBox.Template` does work fine but when I want to bind `ViewModel.Value` to the `TextBox` inside `TextBox.Template` then I always get

> Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ViewModel' property not found on 'object'

Is there a way to set the `DataContext` inside `TextBox.Template` to the `DataContext` from the `Parent`?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type fields:CustomDateFieldView}">
     <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ViewModel.Label}"/>
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type fields:CustomDateFieldView}">
              ....
                <TextBox.Template>
                     <ControlTemplate> 
                         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                         <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ViewModel.Value}"/>
                          ....
                         </Stackpanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </TextBox.Template>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type fields:CustomDateFieldView}">
        <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ViewModel.Label}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type fields:CustomDateFieldView}">
                                  ....
                   <TextBox.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate> 
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewModel.Value, ElementName = myControlName}"/>
                           ....
                        </Stackpanel>
                   </TextBox.Template>
```

If you give an x:Name to your CustomDateFieldView control, you can use this approach. In my example i put as `ElementName` myControlName. This require that myControlName.DataContext is your viewmodel of course

EDIT: if the first approach doesn't work, you can try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type fields:CustomDateFieldView}">
            <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ViewModel.Label}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type fields:CustomDateFieldView}">
                                      ....
                       <TextBox.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate> 
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewModel.Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type fields:CustomDateFieldView}}}"/>
                               ....
                            </Stackpanel>
                       </TextBox.Template>
```

Comment: I tried your binding and put an `ElementName` to my control as follows `<fields:CustomDateFieldView ViewModel="{Binding TestField}" IsEnabled="{Binding TestField.IsEnabled}" x:Name="myControlName"/>` .. did I get something wrong? The control is placed in another file than the `Template` stuff. Does this have impacts?

Comment: @SteveOhio The second approach should work. However, i thought that ViewModel was the datacontext of your control. Instead is a custom property. If you want, you can try again the first approach, but changing DataContext.Value to VIewModel.Value

Comment: now I also have a `<Validation.ErrorTemplate><ControlTemplate>` with a `TextBlock` inside. Have you any suggestion how to bind the validation message to `<Run Text="...."/>`. I tried it in the same way as you suggested above in you EDIT but unfortunately I had no success

Comment: @SteveOhio please ask another question with code and explanation